# SQL string split by text phrase with multiple words into rows

Tags: sql, t-sql

Is there a better way to split strings with multiple text phrases in tSQL?
Scenario:
A questionnaire table with multiple answers complained into a single row.
Answers are category values that I know and some values are more than one word.
See below:

[image]

I'm looking for a string splitter that will also allow text typos.
So far I came up with this and it works, but I'm worried about the performance as I shouldn't use a loop in a SQL function.
It works by adding desired text phrases (up to x5 but can add more) and also picks up the typos.

```
CREATE function [sqlsplit]

(
 @mainstring nvarchar(500),
 @cat1 nvarchar(100),
 @cat2 nvarchar(100),
 @cat3 nvarchar(100),
 @cat4 nvarchar(100),
 @cat5 nvarchar(100) 
 --@cat6 nvarchar(100)

)

returns @t table

(

word varchar(500) not null

)

as begin


DECLARE @rows int = 1,
@item varchar(100)



while (@rows > 0)

BEGIN    

if charindex(@cat1, lower(@mainstring)) = 1  
BEGIN
set @mainstring = substring(@mainstring, len(@cat1) +2 , len(@mainstring) - len(@cat1) ) 
insert into @t values (@cat1)
end

else if charindex(@cat2, lower(@mainstring)) = 1  
BEGIN
set @mainstring = substring(@mainstring, len(@cat2) +2 , len(@mainstring) - len(@cat2) )
insert into @t values (@cat2)
end

ELSE if charindex(@cat3, lower(@mainstring)) = 1  
BEGIN
set @mainstring = substring(@mainstring, len(@cat3) +2 , len(@mainstring) - len(@cat3) )  
insert into @t values (@cat3)
end

ELSE if charindex(@cat4, lower(@mainstring)) = 1  
BEGIN
set @mainstring = substring(@mainstring, len(@cat4) +2 , len(@mainstring) - len(@cat4) )  
insert into @t values (@cat4)
end

ELSE if charindex(@cat5, lower(@mainstring)) = 1  
BEGIN
set @mainstring = substring(@mainstring, len(@cat5) +2 , len(@mainstring) - len(@cat5) )  
insert into @t values (@cat5)
end

ELSE if CHARINDEX(' ', @mainstring, 1) = 0 
BEGIN
insert into @t values (@mainstring)
set @mainstring =''
end

ELSE  
BEGIN
insert into @t values (SUBSTRING(@mainstring, 1, CHARINDEX(' ', @mainstring, 1) ))
set @mainstring = substring(@mainstring, len((SUBSTRING(@mainstring, 1, CHARINDEX(' ', @mainstring, 1) +1 ))),len(@mainstring) )
end


if len(@mainstring) > 0
set @rows = 1
else 
set @rows=0

END
return 
end


select * from sqlsplit('Probably Probably Not related Not related Unlikely Probably Not related Not related Unlikely','Definitely','Probably','Possibly','Unlikely','Not related')
```

Comment: Honestly, you would be better off spending time to fix the schema instead of finding ways around the design issue.

Comment: And maybe install a spell checker or enforce the values that can be inserted. Seems like of people were given explicit choices, they wouldn't be able to enter values like "Posiibly".

Comment: well, it's coming from an Excel spreadsheets in a mass import, so I deal with thousands of questionnaires

Comment: I agree with @squillman, I think `set @rows = 1` is unnecessary here